# What is the process of doing Lingabhishekam?

Tags: shiva, rituals, shiva-lingam

I would like to know the process of doing Lingabhishekam.

1. What are the entities required?
2. What is the order of pouring those entities?
3. What is the best time to do? Can we do it any time?

Comment: Well, most people who do Pujas in their houses don't really pay attention to the actual proper procedures you're supposed to follow.  But the proper procedures  for doing a Linga Abhishekham would be found in the Shaiva Agamas.

Comment: 1. Entities required: pure unwavering mind, strong will and intense concentration. 2. Order of pouring these entities: First focus on Him every thought will be removed, then pour your bhakti and love on His beautiful name & form finally rejoice with His beautiful omnipresence in your Heart, Mind and Soul. 3. Best time to do: Start right now! No better time to pray to the Lord Shiva, the prime Mover, the substrate of all beings, the Creator, Preserver and Destroyer, the Omniscient, Omnipotent and Omnipresent Loving, Kind and One God than Now! All the best :)

Comment: Kinda broad but not really close-worthy, IMHO. Leaving open ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to me the only entity required is a heart full of devotion and a mind filled with His thought.
Externally you need curd ghee honey water and bilva leaves. Pour the water at the last. One thing is never pour coconut water on the shiv linga. I don't know the specific reason . And chant his name continuously while doing the puja. You will get a detailed answer on this topic in the site called Quora.( you type your question on Google and the quora link will come). But as Geeta mentions God sees the love in the offerings . Just think of God all the time and no more ritual is needed. Moreover Lord Shivas other name is Ashutosh that is who is contented in very little and very easily.  Pouring only water is also accepted. 
Time - dawn or morning is the best time. Then your mind is most pure. It's better to take a bath before doing it. On Google search for a pdf book called Lord Siva by Swami Sivananda. Things are well explained there . Hope it helps.
OM NAMAH SHIVAY......